# Or statements in criterion

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a list of orders, which are connected to a user-table. Each order can contain multiple users.

I then have a search area where an admin can search through all orders by searching for e.g. a last name.

If there is done a search for e.g. Smith, all orders where a user named smith should be shown, but how is this done with NHibernate and Criterion?

I first tried (users is a list of users):

`crit.CreateCriteria("Users").Add(Restrictions.Like("LastName", Users))`

but with no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Or statements in criterion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265604/or-statements-in-criterion)

Comment: I saw the post but couldn't use the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Query Over

```
IList<Order> Order = Session.QueryOver<Order>().JoinQueryOver<User>(ord=>ord.user).Where(usr=>usr.LastName.IsSensitiveLike  ("Smith",MatchMode.Starts)).List<Order>();
```

Answer (score 0):

get session in a variable say mySession